# Gymnasium/Petting Zoo: Getting Tic Tac Toe to show ansi text

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, pettingzoo

Using the [Tic Tac Toe environment](https://pettingzoo.farama.org/environments/classic/tictactoe/):

```
from pettingzoo.classic import tictactoe_v3

env = tictactoe_v3.env(render_mode="ansi")
env.reset(seed=1)

env.step(1)
print(env.render())
```

This outputs an empty string '', and also launches an unnecessary/unopenable python window.  It properly displays a graphical board in the new window if I specify render_mode="human", and it also prints a long array to terminal if I specify render_mode="rgb_array".

I just want a text output of my tic tac toe board.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me why the window opens, as I would also expect that with `ansi` render mode the rendering would be done in the terminal. I guess this is some glitch of the tic-tac-toe implementation. What you seem to be looking for is a representation of the environment `state`. However this is not supported by all environments according to [this documentation](https://pettingzoo.farama.org/content/basic_usage/#optional-api-components) - see `state()`. The documentation is a bit misleading for these rendering methods.

Sure enough, for tic-tac-toe:

```
> env.state()

NotImplementedError: state() method has not been implemented in the environment tictactoe_v3.
```

They compute the board state [in the code](https://pettingzoo.farama.org/_modules/pettingzoo/classic/tictactoe/tictactoe/#raw_env.render) to be able to render it (to a window, unfortunately), but that computation is done internally and is not accessible directly. But it so happens that in this game the state is equal to the observations of both players, who see the whole board after every turn. So you can implement your own state method using this. Here is my version:

```python
import numpy as np
from pettingzoo.classic import tictactoe_v3

env = tictactoe_v3.raw_env(render_mode=None)
env.reset(seed=42)

env.step(0)
env.step(1)
env.step(2)
env.step(3)
env.step(4)


def get_state(env):
    obs = env.observe("player_1")["observation"]
    rvl = obs.ravel()

    arr = np.empty(rvl.shape, int)
    arr[::2] = 1
    arr[1::2] = 2

    rvl *= arr

    grp_x = np.array(rvl[::2]).reshape(3, 3).T
    grp_o = np.array(rvl[1::2]).reshape(3, 3).T
    res = grp_x + grp_o

    dct = {1: "X", 2: "O", 0: " "}
    return np.vectorize(dct.get)(res)


res = get_state(env)
print(res)

env.close()
```

Result:

```
[['X' 'O' ' ']
 ['O' 'X' ' ']
 ['X' ' ' ' ']]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Couple questions: 1) It still opens the new python window, even when render_mode=None.  How to fix that? 2) Why did you use raw_env rather than env here?

Comment: Also, one other issue with this code.  It seems that the board flips perspective when you make another move and run this again

Comment: 1. How are you launching? .py file from terminal? From VSCode there is no more window 2. To get rid of initialization of env that performs some initialization that can impact the rendering 3. You mean on the window or on the terminal? This always renders the view of the same player, nothing is flipped on my output... :/

Comment: 1. This is a jupyter notebook in VsCode.  3. I ended up solving this by just passing the agent in and switching `dct` based on it.  Maybe it's reversing perspective on each turn in the code?  common thing for 2 player games

Going to mark this correct.  Since you seem knowledgable about Gymnasium/petting zoo, would appreciate help on this as well: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/43901/gymnasium-petting-zoo-creating-a-copy-of-the-board-env